# Alinear icono a palabra

Tags: html, css

Soy novato en esto del desarrollo web y me ha surgido un problema.

He creado un menú de navegación que al posicionar el ratón sobre el icono se abre.
El problema es que los iconos que he puesto aparecen encima de sus respectivas palabras, en vez de alinearse ambos.

¿Podríais echarme una manita?

Disculpas de antemano si el código os resulta doloroso, es la primera web que "desarrollo"
[image: img1]

```css
 .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(56, 153, 163);
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  .fas fa-chevron-circle-down {
    text-align: center;
}
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd; transition: all 2s;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(49, 110, 117); 
    transition: all 4s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn-box">
            <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <a href="#proyectos"><i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i>Proyectos</li>
                    <a href="#sobremi"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Sobre mi</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ejecutando tu código los íconos están al lado del texto, no entiendo tu problema https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwVDp.png

Comment: Tal y como te dice @Vlady se ven correctamente al lado. Debes de tener algún otro **CSS** afectando al elemento y el cual no muestras aquí. No obstante en el **HTML** que nos pasas tienes unos cierre de etiqueta `</li>` detrás de cada `<a>` cuya apertura es inexistente. Y algunos `<a>` tienen apertura pero no cierre. Yo revisaría eso.

Comment: Cuando cargo el index.html sigo viendo los iconos y su respectiva palabra desalineada, como en la captura que os he adjuntado. Lo malo es que, aunque consiga alinearlos, la fuente se cambia automáticamente. Es decir, si están alineados, es con la fuente predeterminado. Si no están alineados, es con la fuente que he puesto yo... ¿sabéis cómo arreglar aunque sea el problema de la fuente para que salga 'Raleway'? Muchas gracias phpMyGuel por advertirme de eso.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código compartido no se aprecia realmente cual es tu problemática ya que no se corresponde la imagen que adjuntas con el dropdown que compartes. No obstante si tu problema es alienar iconos con texto, existen varias maneras de hacer esto. En este caso te comparto un ejercicio muy simple en el que al poner los elementos 'i' como elemento 'inline' a través del 'css' ya se comporta de manera que ocupa tan solo el espacio que le corresponde por tamaño. En cualquier caso según lo compartes ya de por si deberían comportarse de este modo. Puede ser el ancho asignador a su respectivos contenedores junto con el texto realicen un salto de línea al no disponer de espacio suficiente para colocarse en paralelo, en este caso deberás ajustar el 'width' del contenedor de los elementos. Si lo que vas a mostrar son 'img' en lugar de 'i', entonces deberás realizar la misma acción de cambiar su propiedad de 'display' por defecto, ya que estos elemento son por naturaleza 'block' y deben pasar a 'inline o inline-block' para dejar espacio al resto de contenidos con que comparten contenedor.

Comparto aquí el ejemplo que te comentaba:

```css
.container {margin-top:25px;}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(56, 153, 163);
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }

  .fas fa-chevron-circle-down {
    text-align: center;
}
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
        z-index:9999999999999;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd; transition: all 2s;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(49, 110, 117); 
    transition: all 4s;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content  i, .list-group i {margin-right:15px; display: inline;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 
 <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn-box">
            <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
                    <a href="#proyectos"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Proyectos</a>
                    <a href="#sobremi"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>Sobre mi</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-money"></i>Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-font"></i>Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Ya que usas bootstrap como framework para tu site he incluido otro ejemplo utíl por si quieres hacer esa operación un listado, por ejemplo. Además comparto aquí un enlace a la documentació sobre el uso de dropdowns por si te fuera de utilidad en tu proyecto: [Bootstrap - Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)